# Consolidating multiple worksheets from one specific workbook saved in a folder into one sheet in a new file

Tags: excel, vba, consolidation

In a new workbook, I want the code to search for a specific file in a folder. Then, for that workbook that is found I want to consolidate all the worksheets in that file into a new worksheet in the new workbook. The code I have below works if I am in a workbook already and want to consolidate all sheets in the workbook.

```
Private Sub Consolidation()

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Unmerge cells in all sheets'
 Dim wSheet As Worksheet

 For Each wSheet In Worksheets
 wSheet.UsedRange.Unmerge
 Next wSheet

'Count sheets in excel file'
totalsheets = Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To totalsheets
    If Worksheets(i).Name <> "MasterSheet" Then
    lastRow = Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                    For j = 1 To lastRow
                    Worksheets(i).Activate
                    Worksheets(i).Rows(j).Select
                    Selection.Copy

                    Worksheets("MasterSheet").Activate

                    lastRow = Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

                    Worksheets("Mastersheet").Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select

                    'Paste as values and overlay format'
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

                Next

    End If
Next

                    'Autofit columns and rows'
                    Columns().AutoFit
                    Rows().AutoFit

End Sub
```